# Sending pthread with multiple arguments

Tags: c, pthreads

Im trying to send the thread ID through a struct because I will have to send multiple arguments later on. When I do data->arg1 = t, and try to send data over, then store the thread ID in the PrintHello function, im getting values I shouldn't. If I take out my struct all together and just send t over by itself the program is working as expected. Does anybody know why this could be?

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>      
#include <unistd.h>     
#include <sys/types.h>   
#include <sys/wait.h>   
#include <errno.h>       
#include <strings.h>    
#include <pthread.h>    

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   struct data *someData = threadid;
   long threadsID = someData->arg1;
   sleep(2);
   printf("Thread %ld\n", threadsID);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   pthread_attr_t attr;
   struct myStruct data;
   long t;
   void *status;

   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
     data.arg1 = t;
     pthread_create(&threads[t], &attr, PrintHello, (void *)&data);        
   }

   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
   for ( t=0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++ ) {
      pthread_join(threads[t], &status);

   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);   
}
```

I declared the struct in a separate header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the structure may be updated before the threads read their data.
You should allocate separate structures for each threads.

Try this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   pthread_attr_t attr;
   struct myStruct data[NUM_THREADS];
   long t;
   void *status;

   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
     data[t].arg1 = t;
     pthread_create(&threads[t], &attr, PrintHello, &data[t]);        
   }

   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
   for ( t=0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++ ) {
      pthread_join(threads[t], &status);

   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);   
}
```